# How to get the record object (which is just updated or created) in after_save method in an observer in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using a observer to separate the unrelated logic from the model.

The scenario is, suppose a record is created or updated in a model, then how can we get that record object in the model's observer's after_save method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this in your observer...

```
def after_save(model)
  ---
  # model will the current model object
  ---
end
```

Comment: Check out documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html

Comment: I dont want the model object. I want the record object which was just created or updated.

Answer (score 0):

This observer method is going to be deprecated..
use this

`Model << ActiveXXXXX

after_save :after_save_callback`

### def after_save_callback

### #things to be done

end